How to display HTML help page inside a MUI dialog
I have been google for hours but I can't find anything about how to display a html help file as a popup using React or MUI.   What I am trying to does is create a set of help pages with a standard index.js file.  Using the url or url/bookmark I want to load that section into a MUI dialog that is draggable and allows the user to continue access the main web page.   I have the dialog and can display the html via the iframe (see comment below) but the dialog looks off.  I have a width scroll appearing when I just want the iframe to expand into the Paper container.   How do I adjust the width so there is no scroll, get rid of the border that is just under the iframe?
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

/**
 * Overhead to move dialog around.
 *
 * @param props Positional information
 * @returns {JSX.Element}
 * @constructor
 */
function PaperComponent(props) {
    return (
        <Draggable>
            <Paper {...props} />
        </Draggable>
    );
}

/**
 * The defines the props arguments.  Arguments that where not defined (i.e. other) are unknown.
 */
PaperComponent.propTypes = PropTypes.func.isRequired;

/**
 * Verify the html file exists.
 *
 * @param name Name of html file.
 * @returns {*|null}
 */
const urlPath = (name) => {
    // Name can be: Geolocation.htm#GeolocationHelp or Geolocation.htm
    let bookmark = "";

    // Remove bookmark from file name
    if (name.includes("#")) {
        const words = name.split("#");
        name = words[0];
        bookmark = "#" + words[1];
    }

    try {
        // Import image on demand, ex. "/smartCONFIG/static/media/Geolocation.96c4f2db179d98046b75.htm"
        const urlHelpPath = require("../../html/" + name);

        // If the image doesn't exist, return null
        if (!urlHelpPath) return null;

        // Append bookmark, if any
        return urlHelpPath + bookmark;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(name + " not found in html folder.");
        return null;
    }
};

/**
 * Build the path to the help file and display the html file.
 *
 * @param props This contains all the arguments passed in via attributes.
 *     title - The Dialog title,
 *     HelpPages - Html file you want to display
 * @returns {Element}
 * @constructor
 */
function LoadHTML(props) {
    return (
        <Paper elevation={1} flex={1} overflow="auto">
            <iframe
                id="widget"
                name="widget"
                title={props.title}
                width="90%"
                height="100%"
                style={{ position: "relative", height: "100%" }}
                src={props.HelpPages}
            ></iframe>
        </Paper>
    );
}

/**
 * The defines the props arguments.  Arguments that where not defined (i.e. other) are unknown.
 */
LoadHTML.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

/**
 * Display a help dialog.
 *
 * @param props This contains all the arguments passed in via attributes.
 *     title - The Dialog title,
 *     url - Html file you want to display (bookmarks optional)
 * @returns {Element}
 * @constructor
 */
function HelpDialog(props) {
    // open or close the help dialog
    const [helpOpen, setHelpOpen] = useState(false);

    /*
    Create the help dialog.
     */
    return (
        <>
            <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                onClick={() => setHelpOpen(true)}
            >
                Help
            </Button>

            <Dialog
                open={helpOpen}
                onClose={() => setHelpOpen(false)}
                hideBackdrop
                disableEnforceFocus
                aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
                PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
                style={{
                    position: 'initial',
                    top: '30%', // Position however you like
                    left: '30%',
                    height: 'fit-content',  // Ensures that the dialog is
                    width: 'fit-content',   // exactly the same size as its contents
                }}
                sx={{ '& .MuiPaper-root': { bgcolor: "white", maxWidth: "revert", width: 640 } }}
            >
                <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: 'move' }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
                    {props.title}
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <LoadHTML
                        title={props.title}
                        HelpPages={urlPath(props.url)}
                    />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => setHelpOpen(false)}
                    >
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    );
}

export default HelpDialog;

/**
 * The defines the props arguments.  Arguments that where not defined (i.e. other) are unknown.
 */
HelpDialog.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};


